# How to setup an intermediate git server? And is it advisable?

Tags: git, github, circleci, great-firewall-of-china

## Current Situation

My team is based in Singapore. We needed to install a Django web app inside China for speed reasons for an enterprise client for intranet usage.

[image]

So we did it like this.

## What's wrong?

The git clone is painfully slow and our files are > 50 mb.

## What have you tried?

I am thinking of setting up an intermediate server in HongKong to reduce the latency for git clone.

[image]

Maybe the diagram is a bit off.

We used CircleCI. I think we can get CircleCI to have the following setup.

> Whenever GitHub received an update on the master branch of our repo,
>   the HongKong server will pull the latest master branch copy down.

For the China server, I guess I can configure it to do a git pull every day at some off peak hours using cronjob.

## So what's your issue?

I can google for the git setup steps quite easily like this https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

My concern is whether my approach described above makes sense.

If it makes sense, then my question is **how do I configure the CircleCI to do 
that?**

Our team experience with CircleCi is limited to having it work with GitHub and Heroku. We never have used it with GitHub and a standalone server which we will operate on.

Comment: Do you need to clone the whole git history in the China server? Or do you only need the working copy? If the latter, you could do a shallow clone, which will improve performance

Comment: wow. i didn't know there was such a thing as a shallow clone. I don't mind trying that. yes i only need working copy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a shallow clone in the China server to improve git clone's performance.

For example, if you want only the last version:

`git clone --depth 1 <repository-url>`

You say that your files are > 50 MB, so it will still take a bit to clone if there are many of them, but at least you only download them once.